# textView.getLineCount() is not working as expected

Tags: android, listview, textview

There is a `TextView` inside `ListView`.

I set maxLine of `TextView` through codding like bellow.

```
view.textView.setText("....... Long String.........");
    view.textView.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

        if(view.textView.getLineCount > 4) {
           view.tv_read_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           view.textView.setMaxLines(4);
        }
       }
    });
```

**Problem :** textView.setMaxLine() not working first time. 
textView affected after `ListView` scroll down and scroll up

Comment: have you tried calling textView.setMaxLines(4) before textView.setText()?

Comment: If my textview have more then 4 line then only I want to set maxLine of textView.

Comment: why would you need to count the number of lines if you can limit the number of lines beforehand using setMaxLines()?

Comment: Because there is one functionality : Read more. If my textview have more than 4 line , then Read More is visible otherwise Read More is invisible.

Answer (score 4):

I have an example in `RecyclerView`,this is work well.

```
 mDes.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    mDes.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    int lineCount = mDes.getLineCount();
                    Log.e("TreeObserver", "onBind: " + lineCount1);
                    if (lineCount1 < 4 || isExpand) {
                        mArrowContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        mArrowContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the visible part of your text in the TextView and check if that is equal to the original input, check out this topic [Get current visible text in textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636946/get-current-visible-text-in-textview). I haven't tried the code, but it's worth a shot. You'll get something like this:

```
String input = "....... Long String.........";
view.textView.setMaxLines(4); //this limits the number of lines to 4
view.textView.setText(input);

//now check if the text in your textview is completely visible.
//if not, show ReadMore
int start = view.textView.getLayout().getLineStart(0); //start position
int end = view.textView.getLayout().getLineEnd(textView.getLineCount() - 1); //last visible position

String displayedText = view.textView.getText().toString().substring(start, end); //the piece of text that is in fact visible

if(displayedText.equals(input ){
   //text fits entirely in textview
   view.tv_read_more.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
   //show "read more"
   view.tv_read_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Hmm ok I m working on this now and will be right back after doing this.

Comment: NullPointerException at int start = view.textView.getLayout().getLineStart(0);

Comment: This topic has the solution for the exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558948/how-to-use-textview-getlayout-it-returns-null

Comment: still getting NullPointerException. and Thanks for Help.